# Requirement: In google cloud pubsub subscription, i am trying to set up min-retry-delay to 30 min. Is there any way to do it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

As per the google cloud documentation for pubsub subscription min retry delay can be set from 0 to 600s.
Retry Policy Options. Retry policy specifies how Cloud Pub/Sub retries message delivery for this subscription.

--max-retry-delay=MAX_RETRY_DELAY

The maximum delay between consecutive deliveries of a given message. Value should be between 0 and 600 seconds. Defaults to 10 seconds. Valid values are strings of the form INTEGER[UNIT], where UNIT is one of "s", "m", "h", and "d" for seconds, minutes, hours, and days, respectively. If the unit is omitted, seconds is assumed.

--min-retry-delay=MIN_RETRY_DELAY

The minimum delay between consecutive deliveries of a given message. Value should be between 0 and 600 seconds. Defaults to 10 seconds. Valid values are strings of the form INTEGER[UNIT], where UNIT is one of "s", "m", "h", and "d" for seconds, minutes, hours, and days, respectively. If the unit is omitted, seconds is assumed.

please suggest how to set the min retry delay to 30 mins or is there any way to set it up in google cloud pubsub?

I tried it but getting error

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#exponential_backoff) and based on the error you are getting, the retry policy only allows values between 0 seconds and 600 seconds. You cannot set it to 30 minutes (1800 seconds).